# POST a request to a Spring REST Controller from Wicket

Tags: spring, rest, post, request, wicket

I am just wondering, is it possible to POST a request to Spring REST Controller from a wicket submit ajax link onSubmit() method?

If yes, any example? Because I cannot find good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can use Spring's RestTemplate to do the call to the REST endpoint. Or any other REST client, e.g. Apache CXF.

Comment: perfect, you are the best, you just saved my life! thank you!